# RegEx - Match a number that has different beginnings

Tags: regex

I'm new to RegEx and I'm trying to match a specific number that has 8 digits, and has 3 start options:

- 00
- 15620450000
- VS

For Example:

- 15620450000**12345678**
- VS**12345678**
- 00**12345678**
- 12345678

I don't want to match the 4th option.
Right now I have managed to match the first and third options, but I'm having problems with the second one, I wrote this expression, trying to match the 8 digits under 'Project':

```
156204500|VS|00(?<Project>\d{8})
```

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following regex once.

```
^(?:00|15620450000|VS)(\d{8})$
```

OR to match it with Project try:

```
^(?:00|15620450000|VS)(?<Project>\d{8})$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/IftpPF/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^(?:00|15620450000|VS)  ##Checking value from starting and in a non-capturing group matching 00/15620450000/VS here as per question.
(?<Project>\d{8}        ##Creating group named Project which is making sure value has only 8 digits till end of value.
)$                      ##Closing capturing group here.
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's understand why your solution failed that will help you get around such kind of problems in the future. Your regex, `156204500|VS|00(\d{8})` is processed as follows:

`156204500` OR `VS` OR `00(\d{8})`

In arithmetic,

```
1 + 2 + 3 (4 + 5) <--- (4 + 5) is multiplied with only 3
```

is different from

```
(1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5) <--- (4 + 5) is multiplied with (1 + 2 + 3)
```

This rule is applicable to RegEx as well. Obviously, you intended to use the second form.

By now, you must have already figured out the following [solution](https://regex101.com/r/z5fMDr/1):

```
(15620450000|VS|00)(\d{8})
```

Note that unless you want to capture a group, a capturing group does not make sense and this is where regex has another concept called [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) which you obtain by putting `?:` as the first thing in the parentheses. With a non-capturing group, the final [solution](https://regex101.com/r/5gn4Ev/1) becomes:

```
(?:15620450000|VS|00)\d{8}
```